# htop, show cpu side by side

Tags: linux, htop

How can I show the CPU usage side by side rather than a list?

I have this : 
[image]

but I want to show it like this:
[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to settings (F2), under Meters, you select what is in the left column and what in the right column. Instead of CPUs (1/1) in the left column, select CPUs (1/2) for the left column and CPUs (2/2) for the right column. F10 to save the changes and it's done.

Comment: I needed to run `htop` as root to make the settings persistent.

Comment: If your CPU list takes up the whole screen, going to settings does nothing since it's off the screen. The easiest way to fix this is to maximize your terminal window and decrease font size until you can see the settings.

Answer (score 9):

As I answered to [this more recent version of the same question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/551093/133739), this problem can also occur when you use a version of htoprc that has been optimized for a computer with less CPUs. This is like to happen when you use LDAP or some other system to share your home folder between computers.

You can solve this by deleting `.config/htop/htoprc` and starting htop on the computer with the most cores of the one you use. This will write an htoprc file optimized for many cores (i.e. with four columns for CPUs).

For more details, visit my answer on the other question that I linked above.

Comment: Yes! This is totally true.

Answer (score 3):

Or if `F2` doesn't help, use `Shift-S` which will bring you to `Settings`. You do not need to be `root` to achieve this.

Comment: Neither of these if setting wont display.  I have 40 lines of CPU (out of 128). no settings......  Need to edit the rc file ;  https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/issues/562

Comment: @mckenzm Try deleteing `.config/htop/htoprc` and launch htop on the server with 128 cores. You are most certainly using an htoprc optimized for another computer. See my answer(s) for details.

Comment: Indeed, rm is the great cleanser. You are correct, it is an aws instance.

Answer (score 2):

If you have upgraded CPU and dont care about losing your htop config, then easiest way is

```
mv ~/.config/htop/htoprc ~/.config/htop/htoprc.bak
```

It works because on first run htop automatically tries to arrange cpu monitors in best manner

Answer (score 1):

If you press the `F2` key, you will be able to organize the meters between both columns.